# ¿Cómo ordenar valores DateTime en un listbox?

Tags: c#

Tengo un listbox en el cual agrego fechas seleccionadas de un monthcalendar y quiero ordenarlas, tengo esto:

11/1/2017
12/1/2017
13/1/2017
14/1/2017
3/1/2017
2/1/2017

Quiero esto:

14/1/2017
13/1/2017
12/1/2017
11/1/2017
3/1/2017
2/1/2017

Ojo: tengo el sorted = true, pero no me lo organiza como quiero.

Comment: Primero deberias añadir a tu pregunta como estás añadiendo las fechas al listbox.`ListBox` al poner la propiedad `sorted` a true siempre ordena de modo ascendente.

Answer (score 1):

Como dice @Pikoh, si la propiedad `sorted` está en `true`, se te ordenarán de forma ascendente. Vuelve a dejarla en `false` y cada vez que asignes las fechas, haz lo siguiente:

```
// Vuelcas todos los elementos del ListBox en una lista de fechas
// y los ordenas de forma descendente
List<DateTime> items = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>()
                                     .Select(i => Convert.ToDateTime(i))
                                     .OrderByDescending(i => i)
                                     .ToList();

// Reasignas la colección
listBox1.DataSource = items;
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizar la ordenación de fechas utilizando Linq. Por ejemplo, suponiendo que el formato de fechas está indicado como `dd/MM/yyyy`. Primero tenemos que pasar los valores a una lista de fechas con `List<DateTime>`, aquí es donde haremos la ordenación aunque la fuente sea el `listbox`, luego se limpirán los valores de y posteriormente agregaremos mediante un `foreach` los valores ordenamos nuevamente al `listbox`.

```
DateTime fecha1 = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1);
DateTime fecha2 = new DateTime(2017, 1, 12);
DateTime fecha3 = new DateTime(2017, 1, 13);
DateTime fecha4 = new DateTime(2017, 1, 14);
DateTime fecha5 = new DateTime(2017, 1, 3);
DateTime fecha6 = new DateTime(2017, 1, 2);

listbox.Items.Add(fecha1);
listbox.Items.Add(fecha2);
listbox.Items.Add(fecha3);
listbox.Items.Add(fecha4);
listbox.Items.Add(fecha5);
listbox.Items.Add(fecha6);

List<DateTime> fechas = listbox.Items.Cast<DateTime>().OrderByDescending(t => t.Date).ToList();

listbox.Items.Clear();

foreach (DateTime fecha in fechas)
{
    listbox.Items.Add(fecha);
}
```

**Actualización**

Se ordena por descendiente de acuerdo a como lo requiere el OP.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En este caso, lo que necesitaría OP es `OrderByDescending` al parecer :)

Comment: Tienes razón, actualizaré mi respuesta :)

Comment: ¿Qué es la variable t?

Comment: @JeanHolguin `t` es el nombre del parámetro que utilizas para realizar la sintaxis lambda, puedes utilizar cualquier nombre, no debe ser el nombre de alguna variable antes definida y con esto, por ejemplo, tomando tu código de ejemplo, también puedes poner `x => x.Date` o `item => item.Date` o `elemento => elemento.Date`